# How can I set a default component on client-side only Gatsby.js page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, reach-router

I'm trying to build a signup confirmation page in my Gatsby project. I began with the stater I created here https://github.com/DWboutin/gatsby-react-intl-starter.

In `gatsby-node.js`, I set a pageMatch prop to have my page to handle provided IDs. (Note that `value` is a part of my language building process)

```
if (page.path.match(/^\/client-side-page/)) {
    page.matchPath = (value !== baseLanguage) ? `/${value}/client-side-page/*` : '/client-side-page/*';
}
```

With that, I can access to the page `/client-side-page/{MY ID}`. In that page I use `reach/router` to retrieve the `:id` in the path and render the confirmation form only when it's provided.

**Everything works, but, when I load the page directly, it's shows me the 404 component.**

I tried to set a default route component, for when it can't find the good path. But it keeps showing me the 404 before showing it.

```
<Router basepath={`/${pageContext.matchPath.replace('/*', '/')}`}>
    <ClientSignupDefault default />
    <ClientSignup path=":id" />
</Router>
```

Is there a way to do this or should I find another way to manage this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid the 404 you **must** place a redirect in your web server from `/client-side-page/*` to `/client-side-page/index.html` ie. with ngnix:

```
rewrite ^/client-side-page/([^.]*?/)$ /client-side-page/index.html;
```

there's no other way around this.